# Pandas: Drop duplicates, with a constraint in another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
  Title URL Price Address Rental_Type
0 House URL $600  Auburn  Apartment
1 House URL $600  Auburn  Apartment
2 House URL $900  NY      Apartment
3 Room! URL $1018 NaN     Office
4 Room! URL $910  NaN     Office
```

I'm trying to drop duplicates under `Title`. But I only want to drop rows that have `Rental_Type == 'Office'`. I also have a second constraint. I would like to drop the rows with `Rental_Type == 'Apartment'`, but I want to keep the first duplicate in this scenario. So in this situation row 3 and 4 would drop, and then only row 1 out of row 0/1.

Answer (score 1):

I would build this up in steps to construct a list of incidences you wish to drop.

```
offices = df['Rental_Type'] == 'Office'
apts = df['Rental_Type'] == 'Apartment'

dup_offices = df[offices].duplicated('Title', keep=False)
dup_apts = df[apts].duplicated('Title', keep='first')

to_drop = pd.Index(dup_apts[dup_apts].index.tolist() + \
                   dup_offices[dup_offices].index.tolist())

df = df.drop(to_drop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the duplicates with your constraints in this fashion:

```
  #drop all duplicate with Rental_Type=='Office'
  df1 = df[(df.Rental_Type=='Office')].drop_duplicates(['Title'], keep=False)

  #Capture the duplicate row with Rental_Type=='Apartment'
  df2 = df[(df.Rental_Type=='Apartment')].duplicated(['Title'], keep = 'last')
  df3=df[(df.Rental_Type=='Apartment')][df2.values][1:]

  #Put them together
  df_final = pd.concat([df1,df3])


In [1]: df_final
Out[1]:
    Title   URL Price   Address Rental_Type
1   House   URL 600     Auburn  Apartment
```